# How can I add push notification in my Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, push-notification, angular9

I used Angular 9 in Front End and Asp Dot Net Core as Back-End & MS SQL as Database Server.
My Web App did CRUD Operations. I want to show any changes in the Database occurs. Such as delete any record,or edit or add new account. [My Web Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2kCS.png)

Comment: i think SignalR can use push-notifications and websockets and has a http fallback

Comment: Can you share any tutorial?

Comment: I'm mostly using documentation: [Introduction to ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)